# Usage of that and those

Tags: american-english, pronouns

Which is the current usage of *that* and *those* in the below-mentioned scenario?

> Bar(s) that have been purchased by the customer.

How can this be the right sentence when *that* generally is used to refer singular objects?

Or

> Bar(s) those have been purchased by the customer.

Comment: It's not about the contrast between the demonstrative determinitives "that" and "those", In your example, "that" is a subordinator introducing the relative clause "that have been purchased by the customer". The subordinaor "that" can be used in relative clauses that have a singular or plural antecedent.

Comment: I assume this is a platform where people can ask questions about the English language, even if they are pretty basic or completely stupid. Still, some people gave me a negative, same level of frustration but a different platform.

Comment: @GraphicalDot: It was quite a good question. Take it easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That" as referent applies to both singular as well as plural items.
"Those" is exempted from such cases.
For this reason, "Bars those have... " is incorrect.

The distinction arises when they are used as demonstrative pronouns and demonstrative adjectives.

Thus,
That is my pen; Those are my pens.

and

That apple looks juicy; Those apples look juicy.

Comment: Yes, but the answer to the question is that "that" is a subordinator functioning as a 'marker'. You need to bring out those points.

Answer (score 0):

*That* and *those* are determiners or demonstratives, similar to definite articles but even more definite, if you like. Not just *the chair,* but ***that** chair.* Not just any clothes, but **those** clothes.

However *that* can also be a relative pronoun. As [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/that) has it,

> Used instead of ‘which’, ‘who’, ‘whom’, or ‘when’ to introduce a defining clause, especially one essential to identification.

That's* what is being used in this case: the defining clause identifies the bars you're talking about — the bars which have been purchased by the customer.

If *that* can be replaced by *which,* then it's a relative pronoun. *Those* is not a relative pronoun, so if *which* is appropriate then *those* is not.

It doesn't help that Oxford at least appears not to recognise that fact, and searching for *those* leads directly to *that,* when the words are not simply singular/plural variants.

---

**That* here is an ordinary pronoun.

Comment: Actually, the "that" in the OP's example is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator. It does no more than function as a 'marker' of subordination, just as the "that" in declarative content clauses does. [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/that)

Comment: A subordinator connects a subordinate clause with the main clause. If I say "Bars that have been purchased by the customer are tough", the subordinator performs its function-- connects " Bars are tough" (Main Clause) with "that have been purchased by the customer" (Subordinate Clause). But "that", while connecting, also refers to the antecedent " Bars" and hence should be a relative pronoun instead of being a subordinator. Where am I going wrong with all this?

Comment: @Stockfish Your mistake is in assuming that "that" also refers to an antecedent. It doesn't -- it is simply a subordinator functioning as a marker that introduces the relative clause. It's the relativised element that is anaphoric, and this element may be actually present ("a key **which** she found") or understood ("a key that she found ____"). The understood relativised element is represented by the '____' notation, called 'gap'.

Comment: Not in comments, please. Please add them to the "master"  resources question on Meta.ELU.